# Unable to build and run android app with unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-sdk-2.3

I am using Unity 2018.1.0f2 for building AR apps for android and I already have installed android SDK platforms from 21 to 28. But whenever I am trying to build my project on unity the window says "Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the SDK path is correct". The SDK path is correct but the error persists. What should I do?

Comment: what OS you are using unity on?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Home

Comment: then your sdk path should be if installed standard : c://Users/userName/appdata/android/sdk

Comment: Yeah i have the sdk installed in that very path. When i browse the folder  Unity detects the sdk and asks to use it. But still it gives error